# "TopLevelWrapper.state: must be set to an object or null" - React says

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm crafting my own Webpack configuration.

When I run Webpack development server and trying to see what's my application looks like,
I'm getting a "pretty" couple consisting of one warning and one error.

## +++ The warning (which comes first)

#### Message

```
warning.js:36 Warning: TopLevelWrapper(...): When calling super() in 
`TopLevelWrapper`, make sure to pass up the same props that your 
component's constructor was passed.
```

#### Call stack

```
printWarning @ warning.js:36
warning @ warning.js:60
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:215
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
mountComponentIntoNode @ ReactMount.js:104
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedMountComponentIntoNode @ ReactMount.js:126
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
_renderNewRootComponent @ ReactMount.js:319
_renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ ReactMount.js:401
render @ ReactMount.js:422
119 @ index.tsx:20
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 45a9912…:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 45a9912…:25
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

## +++ The error (which comes last)

#### Message

```
invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: TopLevelWrapper.state: must be set to an 
    object or null
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent 
    (ReactCompositeComponent.js:247)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
    at mountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:104)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:126)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform 
    (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (ReactMount.js:319)
```

#### Call stack

```
invariant @ invariant.js:44
mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:247
mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:45
mountComponentIntoNode @ ReactMount.js:104
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedMountComponentIntoNode @ ReactMount.js:126
perform @ Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97
_renderNewRootComponent @ ReactMount.js:319
_renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ ReactMount.js:401
render @ ReactMount.js:422
119 @ index.tsx:20
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 45a9912…:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 45a9912…:25
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

The error appears both in the Chrome and Firefox, so, It's not probably a browser issue.

I'm using TypeScript in my application.
The TypeScript loader which I'm using is [awesome-typescript-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader).
The process of compiling my TypeScript files consists not only of it.
I'm also using the `babel-loader` after the compilation of TypeScript files to ES6 files.

I've looked at the call stack and I've found out that the error appears when I'm calling `ReactDOM.render()`.

### The script that is causing the error

```
/**
 * @file index.tsx
 * @author Dmitry Guzeev <dmitry.guzeev@yahoo.com>
 */

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// I've commented out these lines in order to minimize the possible scope
// of the error cause.
/* import store, { history as storeHistory } from './store';
 * import AppWrapper from './components/AppWrapper';
 * import App from './components/App';
 *
 */

/* Create the application container element and append it to the document
   body. */
const appContainerElement = document.createElement('div');
appContainerElement.style.height = '100%';
appContainerElement.id = 'root';
document.body.appendChild(appContainerElement);

{/* <AppWrapper store={store} history={storeHistory}>
    <App />
    </AppWrapper>, */}

// Render the application onto the root element

// NOTE (for StackOverflow users): I've tried to render
// the actual application (the component instantiation code is above),
// but I've found out that the "Hello World" doesn't work either.

ReactDOM.render( // <<<<<<<< ERROR IS HERE
    <div>hello world</div>,
    appContainerElement
);
```

### The script that runs the development server

```
/**
 * @file run_dev_server.js
 * @author Dmitry Guzeev <dmitry.guzeev@yahoo.com>
 */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const buildWebpackConfig = require('./build_webpack_config');
const logger = require('./logger');
const constants = require('./constants');
const config = require('./config');

/**
 * @summary
 * Run the development server.
 *
 * @return {undefined}
 */
const runDevServer = () => {
  const buildModeConfig = constants.buildMode.CONTINUOUS_DEV;
  const webpackConfig = buildWebpackConfig(buildModeConfig);
  const bundler = webpack(webpackConfig);
  const webpackDevServer = new WebpackDevServer(bundler, {
    stats: webpackConfig.stats,
    contentBase: false,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  });
  webpackDevServer.listen(config.webpackDevServer.port, 
  config.webpackDevServer.host, () => {
    logger.log('info', 'listening on http://localhost:8080/');
  });
};

runDevServer();
```

### TypeScript compiler configuration file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../src",
    "outDir": "../build/dev",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "paths": {
      "util": ["util"],
      "constants": ["util/constants"]
    },
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "include": [
    "../src/index.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "../node_modules",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

### Note

This is a main entry point of the application, so, nothing else
is imported.

The following code works great (even with imports) when I'm getting the HTML directly from the filesystem.

My package versions:

- react: 15.6.1
- react-dom: 15.6.1
- awesome-typescript-loader: 3.2.1
- webpack: 2.2.0
- webpack-dev-server: 2.5.0

### The actual question

How to fix the error?